# Get inner object from a nested object in chrome app storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-storage

I have a JavaScript object of the type in chrome local storage

```
var obj = { 
    settings: {
        b : {
            e: 2
       },

       c: {
           d: 3 
       },

       ...
    }
}
```

There many inner objects in the object `obj`. Now my aim is to specifically access the attribute `e` of object `b` and change it. I tried the most basic way, i.e fetching the entire `obj` using `chrome.storage.local.get('settings')` and then changing `obj.settings.b.e` value and saving it back. Since, the size of `obj` can very big, I don't want to fetch the entire object into memory. Is there any official means (preferably) or a hack to access the inner objects in a nested object structure ?